# Is there a way I could copy some text to the clipboard so that it pastes neatly into a spreadsheet row?

Tags: javascript, html, web, copy, spreadsheet

I want movie data to populate on the webpage visually looking nice. But with a click of a button, I would like the data points like "Title", "Year", box office numbers, etc. for one movie to be copied with a click of a button so that it pastes neatly into a spreadsheet row. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try like following, this will copy the exact html table to the clipboard which you can directly paste to a spreadsheet.

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: table.innerHTML
    }

    copyToClipboard(format(template, ctx));

    console.log('Text copied to clipboard');
    //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()

function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  document.body.appendChild(dummy);
  dummy.setAttribute('value', text);
  dummy.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Copy Table Text">

<table id="testTable" summary="Code page support in different versions of MS Windows." rules="groups" frame="hsides" border="2">
  <caption>CODE-PAGE SUPPORT IN MICROSOFT WINDOWS</caption>
  <colgroup align="center"></colgroup>
  <colgroup align="left"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2" align="center"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="3" align="center"></colgroup>
  <thead valign="top">
    <tr>
      <th>Code-Page<br>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>ACP</th>
      <th>OEMCP</th>
      <th>Windows<br>NT 3.1</th>
      <th>Windows<br>NT 3.51</th>
      <th>Windows<br>95</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1200</td>
      <td style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">Unicode (BMP of ISO/IEC-10646)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1250</td>
      <td style="font-weight: bold">Windows 3.1 Eastern European</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1251</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Cyrillic</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1252</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 US (ANSI)</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1253</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Greek</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1254</td>
      <td>Windows 3.1 Turkish</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1255</td>
      <td>Hebrew</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1256</td>
      <td>Arabic</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is very cool, but I only want to generate a row to be copied. The spreadsheet is already built. I don't want to copy a table.

Comment: You can use the same approach using jquery to generate the desired output. Instead of html you can separate the data using tab or spaces. Consider upvote if it helped you.